# How to convert dict to dataframe correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

This is the list of dictionary i've got guys :

```
[{'id': 1816, 'name': 'Constantin Gâlcă', 'nickname': None, 'dob': '1972-03-08', 'country': {'id': 187, 'name': 'Romania'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 230, 'name': 'Diego Pablo Simeone', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 11, 'name': 'Argentina'}}]
[{'id': 238, 'name': 'Enrique Setién Solar', 'nickname': 'Quique Setién', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 793, 'name': 'Luis Enrique Martínez García', 'nickname': 'Luis Enrique', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
[{'id': 238, 'name': 'Enrique Setién Solar', 'nickname': 'Quique Setién', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 25, 'name': 'Santiago Hernán Solari Poggio', 'nickname': None, 'dob': '1976-10-07', 'country': {'id': 11, 'name': 'Argentina'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 229, 'name': 'Eusebio Sacristán Mena', 'nickname': 'Eusebio Sacristán', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 677, 'name': 'Joan Francesc Ferrer Sicilia', 'nickname': 'Rubí', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 221, 'name': 'José Luis Mendilibar Etxebarria', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 187, 'name': 'Abelardo Fernández Antuña', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 234, 'name': 'Pablo Javier Machín Díez', 'nickname': 'Pablo Machín', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 576, 'name': 'Sergio González Soriano', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 211, 'name': 'Marcelino García Toral', 'nickname': None, 'dob': '1965-08-14', 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 227, 'name': 'Ernesto Valverde Tejedor', 'nickname': 'Ernesto Valverde', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 182, 'name': 'Javier Calleja Revilla', 'nickname': 'Javi Calleja', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 219, 'name': 'Francisco José López Fernández', 'nickname': 'Paco López', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 767, 'name': 'Gaizka Garitano Aguirre', 'nickname': 'Gaizka Garitano', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 228, 'name': 'José Bordalás Jiménez', 'nickname': 'José Bordalás', 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
[{'id': 36, 'name': 'Josep Guardiola i Sala', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
nan
[{'id': 36, 'name': 'Josep Guardiola i Sala', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 1621, 'name': 'Manuel Enrique Jiménez Jiménez', 'nickname': 'Manolo Jiménez', 'dob': '1964-01-26', 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
[{'id': 36, 'name': 'Josep Guardiola i Sala', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
[{'id': 36, 'name': 'Josep Guardiola i Sala', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
nan
[{'id': 36, 'name': 'Josep Guardiola i Sala', 'nickname': None, 'dob': None, 'country': {'id': 214, 'name': 'Spain'}}]
nan
```

I need this to be a dataframe of something like this:

```
id            name             nickname   dob  country.id country.name
0  220  Francisco JémezMartín Paco Jémez  None   214         Spain
    .
    .
    . 
    NaN   NaN    NaN              NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN
```

Even if there's a NaN value i want it in my dataframe as such ! 
I tried using

```
pd.DataFrame()
```

on the dict elements alone but i get something like this:

```
    id                    name    nickname   dob      country
0  220  Francisco Jémez Martín  Paco Jémez  None  {'id': 214'name':'Spain'}
```

Even if i use **pd.json_normalize()** on dict alone, there are NaN values and so it doesnot go through the entire for loop!

Comment: can you show us more data?

Comment: The dictionary ?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) could help to reshape your data into your expected output :

```
from pandas import json_normalize
json_normalize(data)


     id     name                nickname    dob country.id  country.name
0   220 Francisco Jémez Martín  Paco Jémez  None    214         Spain
```

Comment: What if there's some float objects in it, how to ignore that ? I have NaN values, those are float right ? or how to just fill it as NaN in each columns ?

Comment: I suspect json_normalize will ignore null values; I am not certain about that. Run it on your data and see how it goes

Comment: Error : Float object is not iterable.

Comment: kindly share ur data with nulls and post ur expected output